# Mysql SUM with case statement and multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

```
SUM( CASE WHEN items.items_status != 2 THEN items.items_amount 
ELSE 0
END) as ItemsAmount
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN items ON orders.orders_id = items.orders_id
WHERE orders.orders_status = 1 
group by orders.orders_id 


I get the following:


|     orders_id       |    orders_amount |    orders_status  |     ItemsAmount  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------ |------------------|
|          1          |         10500    |     1             |      10500       |
|          2          |         2500     |     1             |      1300        |
```

I would like to exclude orders when orders_amount = ItemsAmount .
So i have to add another conditions and the first line should be excluded

My two table are ( orders and items ).

table: items

| Item_id | orders_id | items_amount | items_staus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10500 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1200 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 5000 | 1 |

Table : orders

| orders_id | orders_status | orders_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10500 |
| 2 | 2 | 2500 |
| 3 | 2 | 7000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try applying this filter using having clause eg

```sql
SUM( CASE WHEN items.items_status != 2 THEN items.items_amount 
ELSE 0
END) as ItemsAmount
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN items ON orders.orders_id = items.orders_id
WHERE orders.orders_status = 1 
group by orders.orders_id 

HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN items.items_status != 2 THEN items.items_amount 
ELSE 0
END) != orders_amount
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is just add:

```
having orders_amount <> ItemsAmount
```

after the group by.